# PPT Ribbon not accessible after a new VBA macro

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have added a new macro in my custom PPT toolbar, but after this the full PPT ribbon is not accessible. Ribbon works for first time only, after running this new macro, all of PPT ribbon stops responding. I'm sure this is after I have added the new ribbon item using custom ribbon xml. is there a way to attach the pptm file for review, then i will attach here. Thanks.

this is the new update done to ribbon xml to add a button

```
<button id="btnUnifyIcons2"
                        label="Unify Icons"
                        imageMso="DataGraphicIconSet"
                        supertip="Converts the selected icons/groups/shapes into default ZEN icons and Liberty Mutual icons for Constructs creation."
                        onAction="Module1.ShowUnifyIconForm"  />
```

and the new macro code

```vb
    Sub ShowUnifyIconForm()
    frmUnifyIcons.Show
    End Sub
    
    Sub unifyIconOptions(iconType As String)
        If Not icw_CheckReg Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim shp, shpNew, objShp As Shape
    Dim shpNum, iRem As Integer
    
    shpNum = 1
    'Dim strFilepath, strExtn As String
    'strFilepath = "C:\Zen\ZenPic"
    'strExtn = ".jpg"
    Dim oSource As Presentation
    '
    For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        iRem = shpNum Mod 8
        If iRem = 0 Then iRem = 8

    If shp.Type = msoGroup Or shp.Type = msoAutoShape Or shp.Type = msoFreeform Or shp.Type = 28 Or shp.Type = msoPicture Then
        Set oSource = Presentations.Open("C:\Zen\ZenLibrary.pptx", msoFalse, msoFalse, msoTrue)
        oSource.Slides(1).Shapes(iconType & iRem).Copy
        oSource.Close
        With ActivePresentation.Slides(ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
            .Shapes.Paste
            With .Shapes(.Shapes.count)
                .Left = shp.Left
                .Top = shp.Top
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Height = shp.Height
                .Width = shp.Width
            End With
        End With
        shp.Delete

    End If
    shpNum = shpNum + 1
Next

End Sub
```

this is the code in frmunifyIcons form

```
   Private Sub cmdApply_Click()
    Dim iType As String
    If ZenIcon.Value Then
        iType = "ZenIcon"
    ElseIf LibertyBlueIcon.Value Then
        iType = "LibertyBlueIcon"
    ElseIf LibertyWhiteIcon.Value Then
        iType = "LibertyWhiteIcon"
    End If
    unifyIconOptions (iType)
    Unload Me
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, how can I attach files here?

Comment: Side note: are you using [Office RibbonX Editor](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor)? Its "Validate" functionality is pretty handy.

Comment: I don't believe that this code can work: there are at least two topics: First: `ShowUnifyIconForm()` as the callback from the ribbon needs `control As IRibbonControl` as parameter. Second: either you are in `Module1` (like stated in the xml for btnUnifyIcons2) or you are in the module of the userform (see `cmdApply_Click`  using `me`). So propably you should clean up the code plus use validate and "generate callbacks" of RibbonX Editor and then check if the problem still exists.

Comment: added control As IRibbonControl as parameter - before and after validated, custom ui xml is well formed. still not solved. not getting your second point though..

Comment: `Private cmdApply_Click()`:  this sub is presumably located in the modul of the userform frmUnifyIcons. In your code it looks like if `Sub ShowUnifyIconForm()` is in the same modul. But in the onAction-tag of the button you put **Module1**.ShowUnifyIconForm ... and this looks strange to me. Furthermore it would be interesting what other subs are called from the ribbon, like e.g. getVisible etc.

Comment: @Ike attached a screenshot of my project wireframe. all my code are in Module1 only. 
1. Sub ShowUnifyIconForm() is in Module1 only, other module is only to block in unregistered systems
2. no other subs are called other than onAction from the ribbon

Comment: I did ribbon callbacks similarly for others commands also, pls check highlighted frmSettings_show

Comment: Are you opening and closing files in the other commands? And I can see that you have loaded another Add-In (PowerpointwebbrowserAssistant) - try deactivating this one - propably the two Ribbons don't like each other

Comment: yes, I'm opening another ppt file from c:\ to copy some shapes and close it. the ribbon works again after ~1 minute, so this could be the ppt file object is not closing properly? the other addins visible (you have mentioned) are result of debugAddins=1 in regedit to enable viewing code in addins, (I have disabled it now - only this addin in visible).

Comment: I have removed the form and directly called the module callback from the ribbon menu, now it works without any issues. so any idea what would be the issue here?